# Sencha Cmd production build does not respect locale

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs7

The recommended way to set the locale for a Ext JS 7.4.0 modern app is in `app.json`:

```
"requires": [
    "ext-locale"
],
"locale": "de",
```

This works fine for `sencha app build development` but has no effect for `sencha app build production` (the production build just uses the default english locale).

I also tried by setting the build descriptor in `app.json`:

```
"builds": {
    "modern": {
        "toolkit": "modern",
        "locales": [
            "de"
        ]
    }
},
```

Sencha Cmd then processes the `modern-de` instead of the `default` build descriptor, but still, no effect in the production build.

Comment: Doublicate from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68053746/no-ext-locale-package-available-in-extjs-7-3/68282606?noredirect=1#comment120911255_68282606

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The locale package is contained in my commercial download. However, it only gets applied for the development build and not for the testing or production builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in Ext JS 7.2, 7.3, and 7.4. Commenting out the last three Ext.define statements in `ext\modern\locale\overrides\de\locale-de.js` solves the problem as described in [Publishing ext.js 7.2 Modern project with localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621138/publishing-ext-js-7-2-modern-project-with-localization)

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `modern-de` as argument:

```
sencha app build modern-de production
```

For production builds, also check file `.sencha/app/production.properties`.

Comment: Passing the argument directly does not switch the locale from en to de. The .sencha directory does not exist in this project. In all automatically built app.json I see the correct "locale": "de" entry. How could I set the production.properties for the locale?